# How to Display the first 20 messages in the DB

Tags: arrays

I found this code in the internet, it functions as a message box.  The code works perfectly fine.  However, it display all the messages stored in the file message.db.

My question is, how can I make it display only the last 20 posted messages? I'm sorry for asking this. I have no knowledge about programming. I appreciate any help...

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MessageBoardCtrl">
  <form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="email" required/>
    <textarea placeholder="Advertise your link here for Free..." rows="5" style="width:90%" ng-model="message" required=""></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendMessage()">Post</button>
  </form>

  <p>{{item.message}}</p>

<script>
    function MessageBoardCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.message = '';
        $scope.email = '';
        $scope.lastTime = 0;

        $scope.refreshMessages = function() {
            $http.get('../templates/faucet.php/messages?time=' + $scope.lastTime).success(function(data) {
                for(id in data) {
                    item = data[id];
                    $scope.items.unshift(item);
                    if($scope.lastTime<item.time)
                        $scope.lastTime = item.time;
                }
            });
        }

        $scope.sendMessage = function() {
            if(!$scope.message)
                return;
            $http.post('../templates/faucet.php/add_message', {message: $scope.message, email: $scope.email}).success(function() {
                $scope.message = '';
                $scope.refreshMessages();
            });
        }

        $scope.periodicRefresh = function() {
            $scope.refreshMessages();
            $timeout($scope.periodicRefresh, 5000, true);
        }

        $scope.periodicRefresh();
    }
   </script>
```

I found this function to limit the result:

```
function limitToFilter(){
return function(array, limit) {
if (!(array instanceof Array)) return array;
limit = int(limit);
var out = [],
  i, n;

// check that array is iterable
if (!array || !(array instanceof Array))
  return out;

// if abs(limit) exceeds maximum length, trim it
if (limit > array.length)
  limit = array.length;
else if (limit < -array.length)
  limit = -array.length;

if (limit > 0) {
  i = 0;
  n = limit;
} else {
  i = array.length + limit;
  n = array.length;
}

for (; i<n; i++) {
  out.push(array[i]);
}

return out;
```

}
}

Now, I just need help on how to combine them together to make the script work.  I hope someone can help.  I really do not have any idea... Thanks.

Comment: use "limit" in your database query that fetches all messages from DB [EXAMPLE HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

Comment: Hello badaya, thank you for your reply.  As much as I want to, Im having a hard time to make it work.  I think the database is a microsoft Db and not mysql.  Is there a way i can add a function to the script to limit the number of messages displayed?